# Расширить стороны у элемента без смещения других сторон

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Добрый День. На странице находится div. Как можно расширить любую сторону div'a без смещения остальных сторон ?

Comment: А можно пример кода? И больше деталей, и как-то наглядней и конкретней рассказать проблему.

Comment: Проблема в следующем. Есть на странице div. Я при нажатии на край элемента начинаю его вытягивать. При этом "вытягивается" только та сторона, на край которой я нажал. Например div находится по середине страницы и я начинаю вытягивать его правую сторону. Другие стороны div'a не меняют своего положения и остаются на месте.

Comment: нужен чистый javascript, верно или jQuery?

Comment: js + html, без jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var previousX = null;
var previousY = null;

var $div = document.querySelector(".div");

$div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  // left button clicked
  if (e.which === 1) {
    if (previousX !== null && previousY !== null) {
      var left = parseInt(getComputedStyle($div).left);
      var top = parseInt(getComputedStyle($div).top);
      
      var width = parseInt(getComputedStyle($div).width);
      var height = parseInt(getComputedStyle($div).height);
      
      var deltaWidth = e.offsetX - previousX;
      var deltaHeight = e.offsetY - previousY;
      
      if (deltaWidth > 0) {
        $div.style.width = (width + deltaWidth) + "px";
      } else {
       $div.style.left = (left + deltaWidth) + "px"
        $div.style.width = (width - deltaWidth) + "px";
      }
      
      if (deltaHeight > 0) {
       $div.style.height = (height + deltaHeight) + "px";
      } else {
       $div.style.top = (top + deltaHeight) + "px"
        $div.style.height = (height - deltaHeight) + "px";
      }
    }
  
    previousX = e.offsetX;
    previousY = e.offsetY;
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться. Мой вариант , почти копия Вашего